# how to get data from child element to find other child element in xml api with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xml, api

Hey I am new with jQuery thats way i need a little bit help.I am trying to get a specific infos like cpu and ram infos from specific phone model.I write the jQuery code but still i cant render the ram or cpu info even i already get all data.

[image: Hier is the Xml file]

[image: and hier is the attributes ind the same item to belongs product]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://shop.a1.net/is-bin/intershop.static/WFS/Mobilkom-A1Shop-Site/-/de_AT/resources/alle-handys-priv.xml?1622013976098",
      dataType:'xml',
      type:'GET',

      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result)

     
        $(result).find('item').each(function(){
         

        var product_id = $(this).find('productid').text();
      
         
            if( product_id === "bDUK92AjN5YAAAF2NotBee0o"){
            
             let my_product = $(this);
           

             
            // var ram = my_item.find('attributes').attr('ATTR_MAP_RAM').text();
             var ram = my_product.find('attributes').find('ATTR_MAP_RAM').text();
             var cpu = my_product.find('attributes').find('ATTR_MAP_CPU').text();

             var chipset = my_product.find('attributes').find('ATTR_MAP_CHIPSET').text();

           

           
             $('.panel').append(
                
                $('<li />',{
                    text:ram
                  
                }),
                $('<li />',{
                    text:cpu
                  
                })
                ,
                $('<li />',{
                    text:chipset
                  
                })
            )
            
            }
        });
       
        
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
   
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: and what does `let my_product = $(this);` yield? If you log it to the console does it appear as expected or are there errors?

Comment: That API doesn't have CORS enabled, which makes your AJAX request fail. You need to route it through your backend.

Comment: actually i get data as m.fn.init [item, context: item] if i console log my_product :( @ProfessorAbronsius

Comment: @ChrisG okay how i am able to solve this problem ? Seems like i get data from api ?

Comment: The first argument passed to the error callback is the jqXHR. That's what you're logging. At least in the stack snippet.

Comment: I suppose a typo is the problem. You use ATTR_MAP_CPU. But the picture uses ATTR_MAT_CPU .

Comment: With no CORS enabled send the request to your own server ( PHP script for instance ) and use that PHP script to send a curl request to the desired URL - the curl response is then sent back to the Ajax callback

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed ohhh my god it was a typo thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

I think is a typo in your 'ATTR_MAT_XXX', try using:

```js
...
             var ram = my_product.find('attributes').find('ATTR_MAT_RAM').text();
             var cpu = my_product.find('attributes').find('ATTR_MAT_CPU').text();
...
```

Comment: If you're sure, don't post an answer but say so in a comment and flag the question as typo.